# How to change the button colour inside the cell depend upon user selection?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

this is my button when the user select the button it will display another colour.

```
 UIButton *btnClk=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 50, 50)];
    [btnClk setTitle:@"Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnClk.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [btnClk addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:btnClk];
```

METHOD:

```
   -(void)btnClicked:(UIButton *)click
{

         NSIndexPath *ind1=[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:click.tag];
      NSIndexPath *ind2=[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:click.tag];
    if(ind1==ind2)
    {
       btnClk.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400"];
    }
    else
    {
        btnClk.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

the button declaration is global.

Comment: if the button declaration is inside the cell not global than you cannot access that UIButton in your METHOD..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *ind1* and *ind2* will always be the same. What do you try to compare?

And i guess you want to change the code

> **btnClk**.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400"];

to

> **click**.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400"];

Answer (score 0):

if the button declaration is global than you can do these also..i hope it helps..

```
-(void)btnClicked:(UIButton *)click
{
 UIButton *button = (UIButton *)click;
 if(!button.selected)
 {
   btnClk.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"#ffc400"];
    button.selected=YES;
 }
 else
 {
    button.selected=NO;
    btnClk.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
 }
}
```